# FOO.tab.cpp file in folder FOO part of a larger project. Is there special significance of *.tab.cpp?

Tags: c++

This might be difficult to answer. I am trying to understand some codebase and in one of the project folders named FOO there is a main.cpp file plus other .hpp and .cpp files. These filenames are made descriptive using underscores such as Hi_there_file.cpp etc.

There are two files Foo.tab.hpp and Foo.tab.cpp
Is *.tab.cpp an indication of something or just a poor try at making the file name descriptive?

Comment: No significance really, any name(symbol) starting with `foo` is hardly descriptive. This seems to be outcome of overwork or drinking at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that file is generated by a perl script so they put a tab.cpp at the end. maybe even delete this question. Very very specific to what i'm working with